# Loading leaflet.js dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I need to load leaflet.js and leaflet.css files dynamically in javascript. So I am dynamically creating script and link tags and appending them to head of document and using the onload function of script to initialize map.

But I am getting an error "L is not defined"

```
    var leafletScript = document.createElement("script");
    leafletScript.id = "leafletScript"
    leafletScript.type = "text/javascript";
    leafletScript.src = "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(leafletScript);

    var leafletCSS = document.createElement("link");
    leafletCSS.id = "leafletCSS"
    leafletCSS.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    leafletCSS.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    leafletCSS.setAttribute('href', 
        'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(leafletCSS);

    leafletScript.onload = function(){
        console.log(L);
    }
```

Comment: The compiler is correct. Where did you define L?

Comment: if you are used other leaflet js or css plugins , this error will occur .

Comment: I think "L" is not defined will come from other plugins. When other plugins loads first  before your js

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsbin.com/lubupopunu/edit?html,console)

Comment: L is defined in leaflet.js